# How to encrypt existing files with encfs

Tags: encryption, encfs

Encfs documentation explains how to create two new folders (raw storage and mounted folder).

Once a new file is created in the mounted folder, it is automatically encrypted and saved to the raw storage.

I want to encrypt existing files in a directory without copying them twice.

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: copying twice? you create the encrypted folder, copy the files once .. and rename the encrypted folder... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's compare encfs with a simple file encryption

### Encrypt a file using openssl

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -in file.txt -out file.enc  
rm file.txt
```

What happens?

- the contents of file.txt get read exactly once.
- the contents of file.enc get written exactly once.
- a directory entry for file.txt is removed

(you probably want to securely wipe file.txt but I'll skip that)

### Encrypt a file using encfs

```
 cp /normal/file.txt /encrypted/file.txt
 rm /normal/file.txt
```

What happens?

- the contents of /normal/file.txt get read exactly once.
- the contents of /encrypted/file.txt get written exactly once.
- a directory entry for /normal/file.txt is removed

### Conclusion

There's no scope for reducing the amount of IO

Comment: `cp && rm` => `mv` ?